Does online business, only using crypto currency have collect a tax bill before they can release funds back to an individual?
Online platform company, invest small amount of funds to earn a commission by reviewing items.  If an item becomes to expensive you account goes negative and you have to deposit money to clear to finish task.  After all tasks are done if earnings are over $10,000 the company is advising a tax bill has to be paid before funds can be released.  Is this valid?  Does a person have to pay tax on crypto currency 22%

This is almost certainly a scam, but to be sure, you'll need to state which jurisdiction this is happening in, so we know which country's tax laws we're talking about.

And I mean, there's a strong chance that the whole thing has been a scam all along: that your "earnings" don't exist, amounts you "invested" were simply stolen, and sending more money for "taxes" or any other pretext will just increase your loss.

Totally a scam. You need to deposit money to be able to do work for which you're paid? Seriously

First and foremost: Whenever an entity claims that you have to pay them money in order for them to pay you even more money right away, you have a clear sign of a scam there. A legimate entity would simply deduct the tax withholdings, processing fee, etc, from the amount they are going to pay you and just hand over the difference. In this case, this means that there is no commission. Any money you've paid them is gone. Interacting with them any further will not get it back. Report the matter to the relevant law enforcement agency, and let that be the end of this story for you.
To answer the question actually asked, conducting business in cryptocurrency rather than money will not avoid tax liabilities. It is common that an employer has to deduct a certain amount of tax from their employees earnings and send it directly to the relevant tax agency.
